# UK visa for child of EU national

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, eu-citizens, freedom-of-movement

I have Portuguese nationality. My son, 3 years old, and my husband have Indian nationality. We want to move to the UK. Since I have never visited the UK, we applied for EEA family permits for my son and husband. We submitted our applications in the first week of March. We are still waiting for the decision. We are not sure how long it will take to receive the visa. Is there any other way to at least take my 3 year old son along with me to the UK?  Any different type of visa or procedure?

Comment: Mary, did you submit your application directly to the visa center or did you use a third-party agent?  If you used an agent, how much did the agent charge?

Answer (score 2):

The EEA family permit is supposed to be issued by an "accelerated procedure" or some such term.  This should normally be a week or two.  Your best course of action is to follow up on the application on that basis.

Comment: Have already followed up mutliple times from June 1, 2020. The only response they keep giving is that our application is under consideration n waiting for a decision. They will inform us once the decision is made. But am waiting from march 2020. Too long to wait. Cant leave widout son. So looking out if any other options available which i may not be aware of. I see all diff types of visas like spouse, student etc applied in july are being processed immediately. But EEA family permit members still waiting from many months.

Comment: We applied directly to the center. Did the biometrics tru VFS.

Comment: @Mary your best bet is to take a lawyer, because they're probably trying to stall to prevent you from entering before the end of the year (at which point the law changes). Your other option is to find a way to go without your son, get a job, and apply for the EU Settlement Scheme, which would allow you to bring your son and husband even after the end of the year.  Another thing to try would be SOLVIT.  Another option: fly to Paris with a visa from the French, then take a ferry or train to the UK without a family permit.

Comment: @Mary I'm sorry: I edited that comment a few times, and somehow the link for SOLVIT did not survive the process: https://ec.europa.eu/solvit/index_en.htm